# How can I translate a curl command to Python request?

Tags: python, django, curl, shopify, shopify-api

Following [this Shopify tutorial](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/media/products#images-post-request), I'm trying to upload an image to Shopify. A subtask is to translate this curl command to a python request. The file is uploaded by users and I pass the file variable to this function with [request.FILES['filename']](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES):

```
curl -v \
  -F "Content-Type=image/png" \
  -F "success_action_status=201" \
  -F "acl=private" \
  -F "key=tmp/45732462614/products/7156c27e-0331-4bd0-b758-f345afaa90d1/watches_comparison.png" \
  -F "x-goog-date=20221024T181157Z" \
  -F "x-goog-credential=merchant-assets@shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com/20221024/auto/storage/goog4_request" \
  -F "x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256" \
  -F "x-goog-signature=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" \
  -F "policy=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" \
  -F "file=@/Users/shopifyemployee/Desktop/watches_comparison.png" \
   "https://shopify-staged-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/"
```

I use chatgpt to come up with this python code:

```
def uploadImage(stagedTarget, file):
    parameters = stagedTarget["parameters"]
    url = stagedTarget["url"]
    files = {
        'file': file,
    }
    data = {
        'Content-Type': parameters[0]['value'],
        'success_action_status': parameters[1]['value'],
        'acl': parameters[2]['value'],
        'key': parameters[3]['value'],
        'x-goog-date': parameters[4]['value'],
        'x-goog-credential': parameters[5]['value'],
        'x-goog-algorithm': parameters[6]['value'],
        'x-goog-signature': parameters[7]['value'],
        'policy': parameters[8]['value'],
    }
    print(f"{url = }, {data = }")
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
    print(f"{response.status_code = }")
    print(f"{response.text = }")

    response = response.content
    response = json.loads(response)
```

The server gives me this response:

```
web_1      | response.status_code = 400
web_1      | response.text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>EntityTooSmall</Code><Message>Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum object size specified in your Policy Document.</Message><Details>Content-length smaller than lower bound on range</Details></Error>"
```

My file size is only 46KB. I don't know why it's too small. Itried a larger file and it's still the same. I tried to call the curl command to upload a similar local image file and it's ok. What did I do wrong?

Updated:
I try to update the python code like below and it gives me 400 error again:

```
    parameters = stagedTarget["parameters"]
    url = stagedTarget["url"]
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    data = {
        'Content-Type': parameters[0]['value'],
        'success_action_status': parameters[1]['value'],
        'acl': parameters[2]['value'],
        'key': parameters[3]['value'],
        'x-goog-date': parameters[4]['value'],
        'x-goog-credential': parameters[5]['value'],
        'x-goog-algorithm': parameters[6]['value'],
        'x-goog-signature': parameters[7]['value'],
        'policy': parameters[8]['value'],
        'file': file,
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

```
web_1      | response.status_code = 400
web_1      | response.text = 'Bad content type.  Please use multipart.'
```

Comment: Maybe share more context: 
1.What code did you use write (not the chat GPT produced, since as you can see it doesn't solve the problem)?
2.Where / how did it fail?

Comment: What is `file`? How was it opened/passed to `uploadImage()`?

Comment: Did you try this: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api?

Comment: @9769953 I pass request.FILES['filename'] into this file function parameter. The file is attached in the form and passed to the server

Comment: @FabioFilippi I am working with this API. It cannot support the operation listed in the doc.

Comment: If I read [the documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) correctly, you need to *open* the file you're passing. `HttpRequest.FILES['filename']` will just contain the filename, so you're passing just the filename. Perhaps requests is smart enough that it will auto-open the file when passed a string; I don't know, I've never tried. But it's worth a try opening the file (possibly in binary mode), and passing the file object to `uploadImage()` instead.

Comment: @9769953 Yes, you're correct. I change the file variable to file.open(mode='rb'), include it in files: {file: file.open(mode='rb'), ...}. Pass it with response = requests.post(url, files=files). And gives me 201 response! 

I've been working for this issue for a week. You've saved my life. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Yes, but you can use generateStagedUploads/createProductMedia using GraphQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an opened file object (likely in binary mode). Don't pass just the filename: pass `open(request.FILES['filename'], 'rb')` as second argument to `uploadImage()`.

Although it's a bit surprising that requests doesn't raise an error when passed a string for the `files` input. But I assume a string is just file contents for requests, albeit in non-binary mode, so requests doesn't notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file has to be opened in binary mode. I didn't open the file

```
def uploadImage(stagedTarget, file):
    # Get the permannent access_token
    parameters = stagedTarget["parameters"]
    url = stagedTarget["url"]
    files = {
        'Content-Type': parameters[0]['value'],
        'success_action_status': parameters[1]['value'],
        'acl': parameters[2]['value'],
        'key': parameters[3]['value'],
        'x-goog-date': parameters[4]['value'],
        'x-goog-credential': parameters[5]['value'],
        'x-goog-algorithm': parameters[6]['value'],
        'x-goog-signature': parameters[7]['value'],
        'policy': parameters[8]['value'],
        'file': file.open(mode='rb'),
    }
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
    print(f"{response.status_code = }")
    print(f"{response.text = }")

    response = response.content
    response = json.loads(response)
```

Comment: Is it correct that you're passing all data (key-value pairs) through the `files` dict, with `files=files`? And not through `data`?

Comment: Yes, it works like this